# Failed to find style 'bottomNavigationStyle' in current theme Error

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-bottom-nav-view

Tengo un Layout que adentro se encuentra un `BottomNavigationView`, el Layout me reconoce el `BottomNavigationView`, pero me da un error, **Failed to find style 'bottomNavigationStyle' in current theme** ,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y una advertencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le he dado al boton **refresh** pero no hace ningun cambio

Este es el codigo de mi layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Principal_Activity"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">



 <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="60dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1565c0"
        design:menu="@menu/menu_updown"
        tools:context=".Principal_Activity" >

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/inicioItem"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="@string/home" />



    <item
        android:id="@+id/camaraItem"
        android:icon="@drawable/add"
        android:title="@string/camera" />



    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapItem"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_map"
        android:title="@string/map" />

</menu>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.julio.photogo">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application

        android:name=".LogApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Main_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Register_Activity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".SingIn_Activity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".Principal_Activity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".Camera_Activity"></activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de API estás usando? Prueba a seleccionar otra en el editor ¿Tienes declarada la dependencia de las librerías de soporte (support y design)? Debe coincidir la versión de las librerías con el target api que tengas puesto

Comment: El error esta en style.xml agrega ese archivo